# Realtek RTL8822BE does not work in debian-9

Tags: debian, wifi, firmware, realtek

I have installed Debain-9 in my newly bought HP - Probook 455 G6. But it doesnt show wifi connection.

`lspci` shows `Network Controller : ... RTL8822BE ... WiFi adapter`.

I followed instruction [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487048/how-do-i-fix-wifi-in-debian-9) and tried using `apt install firmware-realtek` and using `.deb` package.

But still its not shown. Should I use [these kind](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507136/instal-debian-9-w-o-network-missing-realtek-8812au-driver) of 3rd party package for this?

Spec :
Debian-9 on SSD

Edit : after @GAD3R request for `lspci -knn |grep Net -A3`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11ac 2 × 2 Wi-Fi + Bluetooth 4.2 Combo Adapter (MU-MIMO supported) [103c:831b]
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [103c:85d9]
```

Answer (score 2):

The RTL8822BE firmware has been added to the backports-ed [`firmware-realtek`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/firmware-realtek) package (**it is not available in the main package**) .

You can install it after adding [`backports`](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) to your sources.list:

```
printf "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main non-free" \
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-backports.list
```

The install `firmware-realtek` package:

```
apt update
apt install -t stretch-backports linux-image-amd64
apt install -t stretch-backports firmware-realtek
reboot
```

Comment: still nothing. Its shown in windows.

Comment: FATAL : Module r8822be not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-12-amd64

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram Install the `linux-image-amd64` from backports then reboot.

Comment: I think it just killed my pc. Now it doesn't boot

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram from the grub menu select *Advanced option for debian*  the select `debian with 4.9.0-12`.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram The kernel module `r8822be.ko` is only  available in the backports kernel. Unfortunately backports kernel doesn't work properly for you.