# 0bda:c811 Realtek not recognized

Tags: debian, wifi, hardware

Have a popular realtek chipset usb wifi adapter.  Debian 10 and kali linux both do not recognize the chipset.  Similar problem reported in Mint, Ubuntu, Centos

> @ilak:$ lsusb

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC`

> Adapter does not appear in `ip a` or  `ifconfig` outputs

Based on forum post:
[ubuntu and mint distribution fixes for 0bda:c811 Realtek not recognized as wireless adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162974/wireless-usb-adapter-0bdac811-realtek-semiconductor-corp)

> @ilak:$ sudo apt-get update

> @ilak:$  sudo apt install build-essential git dkms

> @ilak:$ git clone http://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git

> @ilak:$ cd rtl8821CU
> @ilak/rtl8821CU:$ sudo chmod +x dkms-install.sh
> @ilak/rtl8821CU:$  sudo ./dkms-install.sh

`'make' KVER=5.10.0-kali7-amd64....(bad exit status: 2) Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.0-kali7-amd64 (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821CU/5.4.1/build/make.log for more information. error log: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821CU/5.4.1/build/make.log`

- the error log created by install/make: [make.log](https://pastebin.com/K9ZVDvRU)

Is this an issue like:
 [The RTL8822BE firmware has been added to the backports-ed firmware-realtek package (it is not available in the main package) .](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568329/realtek-rtl8822be-does-not-work-in-debian-9)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do (in Debian):

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Update repository in file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then do the system update (with the new `sources.list`):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Download the kernel headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.19.0-14-amd64
```

Clone the Realtek driver source project:

```
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
```

Compile the rtl8821cu module:

```
cd rtl8821CU
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Then do:

```
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

Opening Network-manager, WiFi appeared in the list of possible network types, and when I opened it, it showed me the list of available hotspots.